# Wait for detached container to be running

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-behave, dockerpy

I am using [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) to help write some quite complex BDD tests via [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I am using `containers.run` with `detach=True` since I need to be able to continue my script. A `Given` step creates a container than is then used by a `when` step to do something within it, and finally as expected, a `then` step asserts that the right things were done.

However, I cannot fathom how to have my code wait for the Docker container to be ready to accept data/commands. At the moment, I have an ugly `sleep(60)` in there which clearly is the *wrong way to do it*.

How can I wait for the container to be ready?

Comment: Does the provided solution answer your question? If yes, you could close it. Otherwise, we could provide further assistance

Comment: @bellackn I have done so. Many thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the container you're waiting for runs a service that can clearly communicate its state to the outside world (say, a database that refuses or accepts connections), then you can easily build some try-catch functionality in your tests to check whether the container is ready before the tests start.

However, if there isn't such a thing, you cannot do much besides `sleep`, because (from Docker's perspective) a container can be ready before the  main process inside it is ready (again, a database container could be fully started before the DB process inside it is ready to accept connections, and Docker cannot do much about this).

A possible approach would be to define a new `ENTRYPOINT` for the container you're waiting for that puts a file somewhere that your tests could look for. If the file is there, the tests can start, otherwise `sleep(1)` and look again. Example for an `entrypoint.sh` (not tested):

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# run the process you need here

touch /tmp/i-am-ready

exec "$@"
```

Your tests could then either check for this file in the container directly, or you mount this somewhere as a volume. You would also have to make sure that there still is an attached process after the `touch` thing, otherwise your container will probably `exit 0`.

Comment: Confirmed. This is the way to go.

Comment: This is a nice generic solution. I ended up using something else (namely wait for SSH to be available) but that is very much my own bizarre setup so I would not recommend anyone else using it.